# Performance difference between toString() and +""

Tags: javascript, performance

Is there any advantage or disadvantage between doing

```
var a = b.toString()
```

or

```
var a = b+""
```

from performance wise? Both works and serve the same purpose. We can think of doing it on for example a billion of strings.

Comment: The `+` operation will implicitly involve a call to `.toString()` anyway.

Comment: @Pointy thanks. that was the kind of answer i was looking for. Dont know why my question is marked as dublicate anyway...

Comment: It really depends a lot on the browser. I did some quick benchmarking at https://jsfiddle.net/kfzxprq1/1/ and https://jsfiddle.net/kfzxprq1/2/. When I run these benchmarks in Firefox `b.toString()` is about 10x faster, whereas `b+""` about 10x faster when I run the same benchmarks in Chrome.

Comment: And the winner is (*pause for effect*): **`.toString()`**: https://jsperf.com/35486596